# ApexChart: Allow for the display only the series item clicked on the legend

Tags: charts, toggle, legend, apexcharts, onitemclick

I've used the legend option so the user could select the data he wants to display on the chart.
But there's a lot of info on my chart and when it loads all the legend options are selected.
What I really want is that the chart starts with only one option(legend) select.

All I've done so far is enabled the legend option

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.